# Restore old keyboard on Lollipop

Tags: keyboard, 5.0-lollipop, auto-correct, gboard, gesture-typing

I love Lollipop, but the keyboard is killing me. When I swipe words, the text that shows up in the text box does not match what the suggestion says. It picks the one in the text box and not the one in the suggestions box. I'm used to looking at the suggestions box, and not the text box so it is really throwing me off. Here's an example of what I mean. I swiped the word "this" and it it gives me the correct word in the text box, but the centre suggestion is not the same.

How do I restore that functionality on Lollipop?

[image: this]

Comment: I don't know about this keyboard, but in SwiftKey it's an option. Have you looked in the keyboard settings?

Comment: I've gone through the settings. I changed the theme to holo blur so it looks the same, but the suggestions are still off

Comment: Definitely experiencing the same problem on my Nexus 7 using the stock keyboard. Makes gesture typing really slow.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem and it's driving me mad. The advantage of the old approach is that you tap the suggested word and the strip updates with likely next words. With lollipop the best match on gesture can't be selected in the same manner to then bring up suggested next words.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to settings then to Language and input then choose android keyboard (AOSP) click on appearance and layout after that on choose theme. When you'll click holo you will get your old keyboard back.

Answer (score 0):

You might like using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en_GB&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dgoogle+keyboard&pcampaignid=APPU_FV53VIDRBI7JuATF3IHoDg) instead. It's just like the KitKat keyboard.

Comment: That's what I have right now. It updated along with android

Comment: But this solves the suggestions issue you have mentioned. This is not the stock lollipop keyboard AFAIK.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm using the stock keyboard

Comment: Just try the link mentioned above and check it for yourself.

Comment: I have it installed and no updates available

Comment: My screenshot http://i.imgur.com/eDp0HfT.jpg

Comment: That is really odd